# Cannot import GraphDatabaseFactory

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I am very new to Neo4j and I want to get started with an embedded Neo4j in a Java Application.
I try to create an HelloWorld Application like the following: 
https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded

You can find the source code here:
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.1/manual/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

I created a new maven project and added org.neo4j:neo4j 3.0.3 as a dependency. Unfortunately I cannot import "org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory", all other imports seem to be ok.
Now I figured out, that the import is working for version "3.1.0-SNAPSHOT" of the neo4j dependency.
Here you can find the relevant part of my pom-file:

```
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

Because I want to use a stable version, I want to achieve this with version 3.0.3 as well, but I cannot find something that this factory is depending on this version or how you should do it at version 3.0.3. Can somebody provide information about this?

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your pom.xml.

Comment: I added the dependencies part of my pom file. If I change the version to "3.0.3" it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency you should include in your `pom.xml` is

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

As I see you already included the right dependency. Then I guess something went wrong during the resolving. Therefore [purge](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html) your local repository and resolve the dependency again with following command

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -Dinclude=org.neo4j:neo4j
```

If it's still not working you have to check if you are resolving the artifact from the `maven central repository` or somewhere else.

Comment: It didnt work out at the first time. I tried it several times, also did the full purge:
        mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
and did a project clean. Now it seems to be ok. Thanks!